# Please tell me what tunnel-hull boat set this is?

Tags: set-identification, creator

[image: boat]

I cannot figure out what this set would be...I like it and want to find instructions...but tried different wording and looking at images without luck.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After zooming the image and identifying the windscreen, I searched the Bricklink catalog and found the [#4402 Sea Riders](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=4402-1) set in the list of sets using that windscreen in trans-black:

More details and instructions can be found [here](http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/4402-1).